# powershell iterate through multiple subfolders for differences and move to multiple targets

Tags: powershell, copy, diff

Relatively new to PS.  I am trying to write a PS that will iterate through multiple source and target subfolders with the same folder names.  Do a gci against each folder in both source and target, perform a diff and copy the differences from sources to target.  I have a script working for a single sub-folder.

```
#############  source  #############
$s = "C:\LogBackup\ConversionExpress\"
$src_conexp = [string[]](gci $s -recurse -include *.safe, *.done) #test location


############  target  #############
$t = "C:\LogBackup\ConversionExpress2\"   #TST
$trg_conexp = [string[]](gci $t -recurse -include *.safe, *.done)  #TST


diff -ReferenceObject ($src_conexp) -DifferenceObject ($trg_conexp) -Passthru |
   %  {
       cpi -path $_ -Destination $t -Force
     }
```

My issue is, I have 6 sub-folders in source and target that I need to do a diff against and copy the resulting diff's to the corresponding target file location.

Here is where my ugly R&D has got me:

```
#$pfolder = "C:\LogBackup\" 
$sfolders = $(gci "C:\LogBackup\");
$tfolders = $(gci "C:\LogBackup2\");


foreach ($s in $sfolders) 
{ 
   $sfile = (gci "C:\LogBackup\$_" -r -include *.safe, *.done);   
}
foreach ($t in $tfolders)
{
   $tfile = (gci "C:\LogBackup2\$_" -r -include *.safe, *.done);  


    diff -ReferenceObject ($sfile) -DifferenceObject ($tfile) -Passthru |
                             %  {
                                    cpi -path $_ -Destination $t -Force
                                }

 }
```

I wanted to maybe see if I could get this function I found to work as well.

```
Function GetFiles($folder)
{ 
   Write-Host "+"$folder.Name
   foreach($file in $folder.Files)
   {
       Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
   }

   # Use recursion to loop through all subfolders.
   foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders)
   {
       Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
       GetFiles($Subfolder)
   }
 }
```

any direction or help to get me past this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow why the subfolders matter - if the script for one folder works, and recurses into subfolders, then doesn't that cover all the subfolders anyway?  (and why don't you use Robocopy for this?)

Comment: Is it the files (present/not present) you're diffing or the content of the files?

Comment: If I recurse to all the folders, I can't get the diff's to the correct target since it recurses all the files in every sub-folder for the compare.

Comment: I am diffing files present in source and not in target.  If in source and not in target then copy to target.

Comment: @DonEstes That's exactly what [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) was invented for, so I repeat TessellatingHeckler's question: why don't you use `robocopy` for this?

Comment: Thanks @TessellatingHeckler!  I did some more research on robocopy and and got it to do what I needed.  I didn't realize it was that powerful.